# Barplot of groups based on counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to make barplot

Data are in dataframe. In those dataframes I have several column, one named ID and another count.

First I'm trying to make group of this count. In the barplot we should see,count=0,count=1,count=2,count>=3

Some exemple data

```
data1 <- data.frame(ID="ID_1", count=(rep(seq(0,10,by=1),each=4)))
data2 <- data.frame(ID="ID_2", count=(rep(seq(0,10,by=1),each=4)))
data3 <- data.frame(ID="ID_3", count=(rep(seq(0,10,by=1),each=4)))
```

Obviously here, barplots of the dataframes will look same

I tried to make this in ggplot (it's not nice at all)

```
ggplot(data1)+
geom_bar(aes(x = ID, fill = count),position = "fill")+
geom_bar(data=data2,aes(x = ID, fill = count),position = "fill")+
geom_bar(data=data3,aes(x = ID, fill = count),position = "fill")
```

I got something like that
[image: WhatIgot]
What I'm trying to do is to have different groups within a barplot, like the proportion of counts 0, proportion of counts 1,2 and proportion of counts greater (and equal) to 3.

I expect something like that

[image: WhatIWant]

But of course in my example barplots will look same.
Also if you have some suggestion to change Y axis from 1.00 to 100%.

Also One of my problem is that length of my real dataframes are not equal but it should doesn't matter because I try to get the percentage of count group

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all the data in 1 dataframe, in *long* format. Then cast your counts to factors, and it works.

```
ggplot(bind_rows(data1, data2, data3)) +
geom_bar(aes(x = ID, fill = as.factor(count)), position = "fill") +
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)   # To get the Y axis in percentage
```

[image]

Comment: To get the percentage in y add ` + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` in the resulting plot.

Comment: Thank you actually it works with exemple data.
But I just noticed that I have a problem in my real data.
Lenght of dataframes are not equal. Any idea to deal with that?

Comment: @Nono_sad Do the df's have the same *columns*? They don't need to have the same *number of rows*.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes they have the same columns

Comment: @Nono_sad Then try the code in the answer, it does not seem to depend on df's with an equal number of rows.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I got an error : Length of data.frames are different.
Because the column are same I did something I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

So I did something to try to create my barplot

```
data1$var="first"
data2$var="second"
data3$var="third"
data4$var="fourth"
data5$var="fifth"

full_data=rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5)

ggplot(ppgk) +
geom_bar(aes(x = var, fill = as.factor(Count)), position = "fill")+
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

So I got something like that :
[image]

If Someone have the solution to make different group of counts : count=0,count=1,count=2,count>=3

Comment: This is another question. You should open a new post to ask your question, and accept an answer on this post if it solved your first question.

Comment: This being said, the answer is to create a new column `count_grouped`, where `count_grouped = count` if `count < 3`, and `count_grouped = 3` if `count >= 3`. Then, you can use `count_grouped` as the aesthetic instead of `count`.